# location.href not changing iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to check an iframe src for changes from the parent page.

```
$('myiframe').attr('src');
```

works fine, but when I change the hash of the url via javascript from within the iframe

```
location.href += '#hash';
```

I can see it changed from the iframe inspecting location.href, but from the parent document, src doesn't seem to change. Any help?

**EDIT**

Since the containing page and the iframe are on different domains, I have to inspect it with the src attribute and I can't access the iframe `location.href` property.

Comment: If I remember correctly, changing the hash on a URI doesn't actually reload the page. Until the page reloads the `src` attribute will remain the same on the iframe. If you want to check the iframe's URL, try `$("#myiframe")[0].contentDocument.location.href`. Of course this has two requirements: 1) The iframe must be on the same domain and port as the parent and 2) I'm assuming "myiframe" is the `id` of the iframe you're referencing.

Comment: That is standard behaviour. Setting location.href should only change the `src` attribute of the window object in the current context which in this case is the iFrame document.

Answer (score 3):

the hash-parameter isn't in the property location.href, try

```
location.hash = 'hash';
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether you can do it simply from parent javascript.
Because then I can:

1. create a page, with a hidden iframe. (say http://mysite.com/fake)
2. In the iframe, open some intermediate page within the login process of some website (something similar to https://accounts.google.com/redirlogin)
3. if the cookie for child is present & of there is not enough care taken, the page within the frame will redirect to actual website, with user logged in.
4. From parent page, I can check all the intermediate urls it gone through, which can essentially contain some session IDs.

NOTE: I had done something similar in orkut days & that 'intermediate login page' used to redirect to orkut. This was done for an autologin feature I wanted to implement. However, I could not get any information in parent page.

Notes:

1. I may be completely wrong, but I feel that from security perspective, this will not be possible from pure parent side code. Child should inform the parent.
2. It may indeed work for intra-domain sites.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain frames are allowed to set, but not read, each other's locations. (Why? Well, reading each other's locations would violate the same origin policy, potentially leaking sensitive information that appears in URLs. I'm not exactly sure why setting them is allowed though. Historically sites used the ability to navigate the parent page to [framebust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), but that isn't so relevant anymore.)

So, if you are trying to use hash fragments for cross-domain frame communication (and you can't use postMessage for some reason), then the way to do it is to have the inner frame change the hash fragment of its parent's location, using `window.top.location.href`. The parent page should then check every so often for changes to its hash fragment.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14376395/html/xdomain.html#test) is a demo I found.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works for youtube clips, pdfs and html pages (unless frames are deliberately blocked by the targeted website)

The link will render the document 'htp://someurl' into an anonymous iframe within div id="someID"

```
`<a href="htp://someurl" onclick="renderLink('someID');return false;" title="Click to view external document">view external document</a>`

`function renderLink() {`   
    `if (!e) var e = window.event;`
    `var pdfsrc = e.srcElement.getAttribute('href');`
    `var $pdfdiv = document.getElementById('someID');`
    `var $pdfTarget = $pdfdiv.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];`
    `$pdfTarget.src = pdfsrc;`
   `}`
```